# C++ Boost.serialization vs simple load/save

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I am computational scientist that work with large amount of simulation data and often times I find myself saving/loading data into/from the disk. For simple tasks, like a vector, this is usually as simple as dumping bunch of numbers into a file and that's it.

For more complex stuff, life objects and such, I have save/load member functions. Now, I'm not a *computer scientist*, and thus often times I see terminologies here on SO that I just do not understand (but I love to). One of these that I've came across recently is the subject of *serialization* and `Boost.Serialization` library.

From what I understand serialization is the simply the process of converting your objects into something that can be saved/loaded from dist or be transmitted over a network and such. Considering that at most I need to save/load my objects into/from disk, is there any reason I should switch from the simple load/save functions into `Boost.Serialization`? What would `Boost.Serialization` give me other than what I'm already doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That library takes into accounts many details that could be non very apparent from a purely 'applicative' point of view.

For instance, data portability WRT big/little numeric endianess, pointed data life time, structured containers, versioning, non intrusive extensions, and [more](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). Moreover, it handles the right way the interaction with other *std* or *boost* infrastructure, and dictates a way of code structuring that will reward you with easier code maintenance. You will find ready to use serializers for many (all std & boost ?) containers.

And consider if you need to share your data with someone other, there are chances that referring to a published, mantained, and debugged schema will make things much easier.

Comment: Also: shared and aliased pointers, the bane of all serialization complexity

Comment: @sehe: yes, you express more clearly what I intended with *pointed data life time*

Comment: I'd say that both "structured containers" and "shared pointers" are ultimately just graphs, but certainly in computational science you'll also have other graphs. And especially in graph serialization it helps to have a well-designed library.

Comment: I have to add a qualifier that - since you're in scientific computing - if you're looking to store/transfer large amounts of data, boost.serialization may not be the way to go. It has its up and its downs, one of which is being sometimes unnecessarily verbose.